# Expect : How to create a remote directory thru ssh command

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, tcl, expect

I am trying to create directory in a remote server using the below expect script, but I get an error

```
spawn ssh  $username@$ipaddress 'mkdir $destination/$dir_to_be_copied'
expect "?assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
```

But I get the below error

```
mkdir <MY NEW DIRECTORY>: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The single quotes are not required.

Answer (score 2):

Single quote (`'`) is not special in `Tcl/Expect` so you should write

```
spawn ssh $username@$ipaddress "mkdir $destination/$dir_to_be_copied"
```

or just

```
spawn ssh $username@$ipaddress mkdir $destination/$dir_to_be_copied
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is not due to `Expect`. From the error message, it is highly likely that the folder `$destination` itself not available. 
Check that first.

Try  this

`mkdir -p $destination/$dir_to_be_copied`